# rails form date_select for year with a range of years

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am trying to allow users to select month and year from dropdowns in a form.  the month works great, but the year works but it displays 2015-2025 by default.  I fond one that does work but I am not able to figure out how to add styling so it look likt eh other input fiels.  here is what I have:

```
<%= f.date_select :month_started, {prompt: true, order: [:month]}, class:  'form-control' %>
<%= f.date_select :year_started, {prompt: true, order: [:year]}, class:  'form-control' %>
```

Here is the one that works but I cannot add a class to:

```
<%= f.select :year_started, Date.today.year-90 .. Date.today.year %>
```

Any help is greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref [this](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) to add html options you have to do following.

```
<%= f.select :year_started, Date.today.year-90 .. Date.today.year, {}, {class:  'form-control'} %>
```